# Erro non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r

Boa tarde, tenho o seguinte codigo em R

```
funcao<-function(delta) {delta}
    Intensity2AccumulationFactor<-function(delta,s,t){
    int<-function(s,t) {integrate(funcao,s,t)}
    p=int(s,t)
    b=c(p)
    a=exp(b)
    print(a)
}
```

Ao testar dá o seguinte erro:

> Intensity2AccumulationFactor(funcao,0,1) Error in exp(b) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

alguém me pode ajudar?

O objectivo é calcular `1/(-integral(delta))` entre `s` e `t`.

Comment: Qual erro? Edite a pergunta e adicione o erro pra facilitar que obtenha uma resposta. :)

Comment: Ao testar dá o seguinte erro > Intensity2AccumulationFactor(funcao,0,1)
Error in exp(b) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: Andreia, edite a pergunta pra adicionar o erro lá. Não coloque como comentário. Se possível, adicione também a linha onde dá o erro (note que eu formatei o seu código pra tentar deixar mais legível, mas não sei se está assim mesmo ai pra vc no rstudio - corrija se não estiver, ok?).

Answer (score 3):

Alguns comentários:

Seu código indica que um valor não-numérico foi passado para `exp()` porque você não teve o output que queria da função `int()`. Você deve usar `integrate(funcao,s,t)$value` para ler o valor da integração, pois `integrate()` retorna um objeto `integrate`.

A linha `b=c(p)` não faz nada demais, `c()` não faz nada se receber apenas um argumento.

Tem certeza que `funcao<-function(delta) {delta}` está certo? Essa sua função não faz nada, simplesmente retorna o parâmetro que foi passado a ela.

Apesar de não ter entendido bem o que você quer com `delta`, você pode simplificar seu código assim:

```
funcao<-function(delta) {delta}

Intensity2AccumulationFactor <- function(s,t){  
  exp(integrate(funcao,s,t)$value)    
}

Intensity2AccumulationFactor(0, 3)
```

A variável `delta` que você passou pra `Intensity2AccumulationFactor` não era utilizada, e o resultado nesse caso é o exponencial da integração de `s` até `t`.

Comment: Obrigado, coma sua ajuda já resolvi o problema :)

Comment: @AndreiaSilva, se essa resposta te atendeu, você pode aceitá-la.